# Azure App Service Web App compilation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

After sucesfully publishing my app trough Azure web deploy, I am facing this error upon opening the website:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request.
Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -532462766.
```

> How can I address this issue?

Comment: Does this only fail when hosted in Azure, or does it fail locally as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This compilation error is due to issues with .DLL's uploaded in the past. It can happen if you have uploaded previously with web deploy, and Visual Studio did not correctly detect dependency updates on a second deploy, therefor not deploying the changed .DLL.

**Update:** The best solution is while updating the website trough Web Deploy, select the `Remove additional files at destination` option under `File Publishing Options`

Comment: There is an option in your web deploy config to delete extra files. Check it and it will clear this issue (assuming that this answer would solve your problem, which I my experience happens all the time)

Comment: Yeah, I ended up finding this option the second time I ran into this problem, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Application Logging, Web Server, Detailed Error, and Failed Request tracing in your diagnostic options on Azure

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

FTP the logs down and see if this helps.